# release wakelock in service? (wakelock always under-locked)

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I need help implementing wakelock in android...

I'm trying to create an audio recorder app, and during recording, the device should be able to stay recording even though screen is dimmed, so I used the wakelock with partial wakelock to keep cpu working.

I put the recording process to a Service and acquire the wakelock in it, when recording started, and releasing it when recording stopped.

However, when I try to release the wakelock, I always get the  `WakeLock under-locked RecordingWakeLock`. `isHeld()` is always returning `false` before and after releasing the wakelock, even though it throws me the `under-locked` error.

**Is there anyway to release the wakelock in the service?**

This is my code: (simplified to the only the wakelock related code)

```
public class RecordingService extends Service {

private static wakeLock;

private BroadcastReceiver newRecordReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "newRecordReceiver");

            //Check for audio focus state and request if needed
            requestAudioFocus();

            //check and request wakelock
            if (wakeLock == null) {
                PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "RecordingWakeLock");
            } else {
                wakeLock.acquire();
                wakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
            }

            //start/resume recording
            startRecording();
        }
    };

private BroadcastReceiver pauseRecordReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "pauseRecordReceiver");
            //stop/pause recording
            stopRecording();
        }
    };

private void startRecording() {

        //start recording here...

        isRecording = true;
        recordPaused = false;
    }

private void stopRecording() {
        Log.d(TAG, "stopRecording");

        recordPaused = true;
        isRecording = false;

        Log.d(TAG, "wakelock is held before release:" + wakeLock.isHeld());

        //check for wakelock, and release it if possible
        try {
            if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "wakelock is held:" + wakeLock.isHeld());

        //stop recording here....
    }
}
```